# Getting objects updated in last 10 seconds from ActiveRecord's find

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, find

I'd like to get the objects that are updated in the last 10 seconds from the ActiveRecord's find.

I tried doing this

```
@chats = Chat.find(:all, :conditions => ["updated_at > ?", 10.seconds.ago] )
```

as well as

```
@chats = Chat.find(:all, :conditions => ["updated_at > ?", Time.now-10.seconds] )
```

and even

```
@chats = Chat.find(:all, :conditions => {:updated_at => 10.seconds.ago..0.seconds.ago}]
```

But I still can't get it to work :(

EDIT: I am updating the column from another application to keep it alive and I'm looking at all the rows I kept alive in the last 10 seconds, to dispose the dead chats.

Comment: What do the resulting queries look like in your log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that you are querying on the right column?  I am thinking that you might need to look at the created_at timestamp instead.  I don't know your application, but I am surprised you are updating existing chats, instead of just inserting new ones.

So... if my assumption is correct, this might be what you are looking for:

```
@chats = Chat.find(:all, :conditions => ["created_at > ?", 10.seconds.ago] )
```

If not... please provide a little more info.  The query should work as you have it, and I am guessing the updated_at may not be getting updated.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for replying. I updated the post. Basically, I need to display only alive columns and I am modifying a column to keep alive.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the date is being updated in your Rails app, and that the date is in the correct format for your database?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in UTC-default of Rails. I changed it to 
  config.time_zone = 'Pacific Time (US & Canada)'
and now it works alright :)

Comment: Ahhhhh, yes.  I guess that would do it, if your systems were not using the same time zone.